# Когда нужно использовать asincio.run_forever()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, asyncio

Не могу понять механизм работы функции цикла событий `run_forever()`, в каких случаях нужно использовать `run_forever()`?

Comment: Когда код должен работать всегда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run_forever() запускается когда нужно обрабатывать все события в программе. Например, вы запустили сервер, который будет работать до завершения программы пользователем.

run_until_complete() запускается ради одного события. Например, создали сервер - сохранили на него ссылку, а дальше run_forever(). Если Ваша программа использует асинхронные вещи разово, то можно их запускать через run_until_complete()